# Router, switch configuration in linux

Tags: networking, router, dhcp, switch

Can someone suggest a good book for router and switch configuration in linux. I also want to configure dhcp, dns and other stuff.

Regards
Bala

Comment: suggest a good what?

Comment: I'm pretty sure he meant book!  oops really old qestion.

Answer (score 1):

firewall distribution solutions (very recomended, if you do not have much experience...):
http://www.endian.com and IPCOP firewall (http://sourceforge.net/apps/trac/ipcop/wiki)

Comment: sorry - i am not allowed to post more than one link in the answer :-)

for a simple zone-based firewall i would suggest: http://shorewall.net/

very simple and easy dns and dhcp: http://thekelleys.org.uk/dnsmasq/doc.html

if you prefer a more professional setup use: ics-dcp and bind (both from (https://www.isc.org/)

Comment: I need something for linux.

Answer (score 0):

Do you mean you are looking for firewall software for Linux?

Vuurmuur is my favourite for that:

https://www.vuurmuur.org/trac/

It has a easy to use curses interface and a bunch of features that would be needed for a firewall. But that's it, it does not do DNS/DHCP, etc... that you need to do the regular way.

I ran it for years on a few of my servers before switching to PFSense.